# Starting Activity With Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `NavigationDrawerActivity` called `MainActivity`.  I have another activity that appears as a dialog over my `Mainctivity` called `GuestActivity`.

I have two fragments that open with my `MainActivity`; `HomeFragment` and `RegisterFragment`.

I have a button in my `GuestActivity`, now when that button is clicked I want the `GuestActivity` to close and then open my `MainActivity` with my `RegisterFragment` loaded.

Is there a way to do this and if so how? Could I please see an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start `GuestActivity` with `startActivityForResult`. This way you can set the result with the button click and change the fragment in the MainActivity accordingly without starting the MainActivity again.

In your MainActivity change to:

```
    startActivityForResult(guestIntent, 1337);
```

And override the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == 1337) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        // Change framgnet
    }
}
}
```

In the onClickListener of the button in the GuestActivity add:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
GuestActivity.this.finish(();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press button then call below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("start_register_fragment", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Now in MainActivity onCreate method check

```
if(getIntent.getExtras.getBoolean("start_register_fragment")) {
//call to register fragment here
}
```